# Python Mechanize upload

Tags: javascript, python, file, upload, mechanize

Hi I have been using mechanize and python to try and upload a file to a website, so far Ive been succesfull but im stuck at the upload page. I know mechanize does not work with JavaScript but I was wondering if anyone knows a way that I could pass a file directory to the form to upload it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssABI.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ABIDynamicMenus.css" />
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Provided by Aeries Browser Interface</title>
<script language="JavaScript" src="ABIjava.js"></script>
</head>
<body vlink="Blue">

    <form name="frmValues" id="frmValues" method="post" action="FileUpload/Default.aspx?cache=5%2F19%2F2011+5%3A02%3A22+PM&LoadID=txtUploadedFileID&LoadNM=">
        <input type="hidden" name="UserType" id="UserType" value="P" />
        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="69297" />
        <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" value="200673" /
        <input type="hidden" name="Check1" id="Check1" value="c91097e8cad20b230024a190d8867b3c65aceaaef6297c3788dd5b017bb89b2b" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Check2" id="Check2" value="163f01c431991367a988152a35b947fa339359a7124c8fe9bc390d9c06f48a16" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('frmValues').submit();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize handles file uploads to forms like this:

`form.add_file(open("NAME/LOCATION OF FILE"), "MIME TYPE", "NAME OF FILE")`

```
br.form.add_file(open("file.txt"), "text/plain", "file.txt")
```